# How to get the desired output by using min function in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am using this below query in mysql

```
SELECT count(c.id), u.id FROM users AS u 
INNER JOIN zipcode_users_1_c AS zu ON zu.zipcode_users_1users_idb = u.id 
LEFT JOIN zipcode AS z ON z.id = zu.zipcode_users_1zipcode_ida 
LEFT JOIN branches AS b ON u.branch_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN branches_loan_1_c AS bl ON b.id = bl.branches_loan_1branches_ida 
LEFT JOIN loan AS l ON l.id = bl.branches_loan_1loan_idb 
LEFT JOIN accounts_loan_1_c AS al ON l.id = al.accounts_loan_1loan_idb 
LEFT JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = accounts_loan_1accounts_ida 
LEFT JOIN cases_cstm as cc on u.id = cc.user_id_c 
LEFT JOIN cases as c on cc.id_c = c.id 
AND u.deleted = 0 AND zu.deleted = 0 AND z.deleted = 0 AND bl.deleted = 0 AND b.deleted = 0 AND AND l.deleted = 0 AND al.deleted = 0 AND a.deleted = 0 and c.deleted = 0 WHERE l.id = '34599008-3931-a6e1-b736-5795f5e9ff0b' AND z.code = a.billing_address_postalcode AND u.status = 'Active' group by u.id
```

and I am getting this result

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| count(c.id) | id                                   |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
|           4 | 40fc0f12-97a5-cd06-cf42-57961a48ee28 |
|           0 | 84ce03df-dc38-6920-e4d4-543792545b5a |
|           3 | 88f6a311-9f15-c50e-cf09-5753e764dd18 |
|           0 | 46ce0bd2-dc28-6921-24d4-547792515346 |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Now, here I want only those record where count(c.id) is very low i.e. in this case there will be only two records with count(c.id) is 0. I am looking forward to use min() function but I am getting "Invalid use of group function" error, if I use min() function with count() function. So, kindly guide me here. Thank you.

Comment: for what I got "-1", may i know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really format your query better. Put the join conditions on in the join they belong to, **not** like this

```
LEFT JOIN cases as c on cc.id_c = c.id 
AND u.deleted = 0 AND zu.deleted = 0 AND z.deleted = 0 AND bl.deleted = 0
```

Then in your `where` clause your conditions turn your `left join`s into `inner join`s.

To solve your problem, put the query you have in a subquery. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html) has an excellent entry which explains how to solve your problem:

Quote:

### The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column

Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most expensive price.

This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);
```

The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.

**Uncorrelated subquery:**

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

**LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows values will be NULL.

**Clarification:**

To illustrate more easily, I create a view of your query like this:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS
SELECT count(c.id) AS cnt, .../*the rest of your query*/
```

Now, you need the minimum value of your count()..

```
SELECT MIN(cnt) FROM foo;
```

Now you want the rows corresponding to this value.

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE cnt = (SELECT MIN(cnt) FROM foo);
```

Comment: Hello @fancyPants, can you explain more exactly with my query? as I am not able to understand how to use subquery/uncorrelated query in this scenario.

Comment: Hey @fancyPants, I tried your way by creating view and it worked. Thanks. But I am looking forward to achieve the same result with only one query rather than this. But still thanks for reminding about using view as I had totally forgot that.

Comment: You don't have to use a view, it was for convenience. But the principal stays the same. You just have to put your queriy in subqueries.

Comment: but I can't use only subquery as you said, with "=" operator. As in my query "cnt" is a md5 string as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Er, what? I can't follow you here. You don't compare the md5 string, you compare the count!

Comment: ok, I now understand, but it doesn't make sense, because i'll have to use entire query twice, and it will be a big one. Looking forward with some other options if there any.

Comment: There are none and it probably won't exactly be executed twice. There are mechanisms like query_cache / result buffer and so on. Have you tried the query? Is it too slow? Then post a question how to improve performance where you include info about your tables and indexes and the result of `EXPLAIN <your query>`.

Comment: ok thanks, @fancyPants. I have not tried query with large no. of records, I'll check and if it slow, I'll post new question. Thanks anyway. So, I am choosing your answer as a correct one.

Comment: I don't know what happened, stackoverflow restricts me from posting new question, I don't what happened. Also got "-1" on my question, but no explanation on that. :(

Comment: I don't know either, but this site http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is the place to ask. It's for questions / discussions etc. about stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

How are you using the min() function with count() function ?

I suggest you to try this :

`SELECT MIN(cnt) FROM (SELECT COUNT(c.id) cnt, u.id /* .. etc same as before... */)`

Although I can't try this by myself, I think it should work. Let us know.

Comment: That will only get the minimum value - not all records (including id) with min count

Comment: Then, if we use the same logic, maybe this can work : `SELECT MIN(cnt), inc_uid FROM (SELECT COUNT(c.id) cnt, u.id inc_uid/* .. etc same as before... */) GROUP BY inc_uid;`

Comment: Consider this query: `select min(whatever), max(whatever), foo from bar group by foo`. Do you see the problem with your approach now?

Comment: Hello @Ekto, I tried that and I get the result according to the min condition but it is not showing its corresponding id, it is showing wrong id.